# Writing korean characters to zipped csv file in Java

Tags: java, csv, zip

I'm writing a csv file that I also need to zip, and am using java.util.zip.ZipEntry and java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.

It all works great when I have western characters in all the columns, but when I use Korean characters it fails to recognize the /n and everything appears messed up and on the same row.  I'm writing it as UTF-8 characters, and expect this covers korean.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class CreateCSV {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime().toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTime newDateTime = utcDateTime.toDateTime();
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-SSS-");
    File zipFile = new File("C:/TestCSVKorean/"+ dateFormatter.print(newDateTime) + "Export.zip");

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
    // Open up the zipfile and create the csv entry
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream));
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(dateFormatter.print(newDateTime) + "tics.csv"));
    // The first line of the CSV is a header line
    StringBuffer csvHeader = new StringBuffer(
            "Time,Name,Rev,Appme,EnvName,PlanName,PlanRev,"
                + "Og Name,Op Name,"
              + "TTR,Lat,Bys Rec,Bytt,"
                    + "RPl,Request Method,URI Path,Query String,HTTP Status Code,"
                    + "HTTP Request Headers,User Agent,Request Body,HTTP Response Headers,Response Body\n");
    zos.write(csvHeader.toString().getBytes(), 0, csvHeader.length());

    StringBuffer csvData = new StringBuffer("");

    csvData.append("\"" + newDateTime + "\",\"" +
            "apiName" + "\"," +
            "2.0.0" + ",\"" + 
            "app name" + "\",\"" +
            "env name" + "\",\"" +
            "plan name" + "\"," +
            "2" + ",\"" +
            "dev org name" + "\",\"" +
            "ìº˜ë¦°ë” ëª©ë¡ì¡°íšŒ(ë‚´ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, êµ¬ë…ê°€ëŠ¥í•œ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, ê´€ë¦¬ìž ìº˜ë¦°ë”)" + "\"," +
            "123" + "," +
            "inifd: 334;dshs: 343" + ", " +
            "10" + "," + 
            "33" + ",\"" + 
            "http" + "\",\"" + 
            "GET" + "\",\"" + 
            "/dsfs/sdf/ds" + "\",\"" + "query string" + "\",\"" + 
            "200" + "\",\"" + 
            "jshkshdf" + "\",\"" + 
            "sdjhfks/sdfs/" + "\",\"" +                             
            "jhksdfhks dsfs" + "\",\"" +    
            "dsfsdfs" + "\",\"" +       
            "dsfsfs" + "\"\n"); 

    zos.write(csvData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, csvData.length());

    csvData = new StringBuffer("");

    csvData.append("\"" + newDateTime + "\",\"" +
            "apiName" + "\"," +
            "2.0.0" + ",\"" + 
            "app name" + "\",\"" +
            "env name" + "\",\"" +
            "plan name" + "\"," +
            "2" + ",\"" +
            "dev org name" + "\",\"" +
            "ìº˜ë¦°ë” ëª©ë¡ì¡°íšŒ(ë‚´ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, êµ¬ë…ê°€ëŠ¥í•œ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, ê´€ë¦¬ìž ìº˜ë¦°ë”)" + "\"," +
            "123" + "," +
            "inifd: 334;dshs: 343" + ", " +
            "10" + "," + 
            "33" + ",\"" + 
            "http" + "\",\"" + 
            "GET" + "\",\"" + 
            "/dsfs/sdf/ds" + "\",\"" + "query string" + "\",\"" + 
            "200" + "\",\"" + 
            "jshkshdf" + "\",\"" + 
            "sdjhfks/sdfs/" + "\",\"" +                             
            "jhksdfhks dsfs" + "\",\"" +    
            "dsfsdfs" + "\",\"" +       
            "dsfsfs" + "\"\n"); 


    zos.write(csvData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, csvData.length());

    zos.close();

}
```

}

This is what I see when I open the csv file:

Time    Name    Rev Appme   EnvName PlanName    PlanRev Og Name Op Name TTR Lat Bys Rec Bytt    RPl Request Method  URI Path    Query String    HTTP Status Code    HTTP Request Headers    User Agent  Request Body    HTTP Response Headers   Response Body
2016-01-28T17:20:56.859Z    apiName 2.0.0   app name    env name    plan name   2   dev org name    Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€ Ã«ÂªÂ©Ã«Â¡ÂÃ¬Â¡Â°Ã­Å¡Å’(Ã«â€šÂ´ Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€, ÃªÂµÂ¬Ã«Ââ€¦ÃªÂ°â‚¬Ã«Å Â¥Ã­â€¢Å“ Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€, Ã¬â€¹Å“Ã¬Å Â¤Ã­â€¦Å“ Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€, ÃªÂ´â‚¬Ã«Â¦Â¬Ã¬Å¾Â Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€) 123 inifd: 334;dshs: 343    10  33  http    2016-01-28T17:20:56.859Z    apiName 2.0.0   app name    env name    plan name   2   dev org name    Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€ Ã«ÂªÂ©Ã«Â¡ÂÃ¬Â¡Â°Ã­Å¡Å’(Ã«â€šÂ´ Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€, ÃªÂµÂ¬Ã«Ââ€¦ÃªÂ°â‚¬Ã«Å Â¥Ã­â€¢Å“ Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€, Ã¬â€¹Å“Ã¬Å Â¤Ã­â€¦Å“ Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€, ÃªÂ´â‚¬Ã«Â¦Â¬Ã¬Å¾Â Ã¬ÂºËœÃ«Â¦Â°Ã«Ââ€) 123 inifd: 334;dshs: 343    10  33  http

It is sticking the date field from the second row into the Request method field of the first: 2016-01-28T17:20:56.859Z

Comment: Your CSV file looks correct.  The problem is in how you're viewing it.  What program are you using to open it?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should get out of the habit of using StringBuffer.  It's an obsolete class.  If you need to append text little by little, you would normally use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

In your case, however, you don't need StringBuilder or StringBuffer.  Just use the string:

```
String csvHeader =
        "Time,Name,Rev,Appme,EnvName,PlanName,PlanRev,"
            + "Og Name,Op Name,"
          + "TTR,Lat,Bys Rec,Bytt,"
                + "RPl,Request Method,URI Path,Query String,HTTP Status Code,"
                + "HTTP Request Headers,User Agent,Request Body,HTTP Response Headers,Response Body\n";
```

And…

```
String csvData = "\"" + newDateTime + "\",\"" +
        "apiName" + "\"," +
        "2.0.0" + ",\"" + 
        "app name" + "\",\"" +
        // etc.
```

Second, be careful not to confuse byte count with character count.  When you convert a String to bytes using the UTF-8 charset, any characters not in the US-ASCII range (0-127) will be converted to more than one byte.  Therefore, the number of bytes will be larger than the String's length (which represents how many characters it contains, not how many bytes it takes up when encoded in UTF-8).

So your write operation should just be:

```
zos.write(csvData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Third, I don't know Korean, but I know what Hangul characters look like, and I don't see any in your code.  I assume you intended these to be Hangul:

```
"ìº˜ë¦°ë” ëª©ë¡ì¡°íšŒ(ë‚´ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, êµ¬ë…ê°€ëŠ¥í•œ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ ìº˜ë¦°ë”, ê´€ë¦¬ìž ìº˜ë¦°ë”)" + "\"," +
```

It appears you're using Windows to place each individual UTF-8 byte in your String as if it were a character.  But in Java, bytes are *not* characters, and are not interchangeable with characters.

I assume your use of Windows, because the third character, the spacing Unicode character [SMALL TILDE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02dc/), is `\u02dc` which would normally take up two bytes, but in the windows-1252 encoding, it is the single byte 0x98.

So, if I assume you derived those characters from the UTF-8 bytes of Hangul characters, the first six bytes in the above string are:

```
ec ba 98 eb a6 b0
ì  º  ˜  ë  ¦  °
```

Those bytes are the UTF-8 representation of the two Hangul characters U+CE98 and U+B9B0.  The correct way to place those two characters in a Java string is:

```
"\uce98\ub9b0"
```

If you have the original Hangul text in a file, you can easily convert the entire text to a series of Java escape sequences like the above line, using the [native2ascii](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html) tool that comes with every JDK.  Such a command might look like:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 hangul.txt hangulstrings.java
```

An alternative approach which I don't recommend, if you don't want to be bothered to write your Strings correctly, is to force your current "pseudo-bytes" string to be interpreted as UTF-8 bytes by recognizing that it contains Windows-1252 characters representing bytes and restoring it to those bytes:

```
zos.write(csvData.getBytes("windows-1252"));
```

The resulting zip entry will still be encoded in UTF-8, since your bytes are a UTF-8 representation of your Hangul text.  So you need to make sure you open the file using a tool that recognizes that the file is UTF-8.

Windows is not especially good at recognizing a UTF-8 file.  Notepad is especially poor at it.  One way to signal to Windows that a file is a UTF-8 file is to write a Byte Order Mark character as the first character in the file:

```
String csvHeader = "\ufeff"
        + "Time,Name,Rev,Appme,EnvName,PlanName,PlanRev,"
        // etc.
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, many thanks.  This worked: zos.write(csvData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));